# Generate Interface from an object in Typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, interface

I have a `Typescript` project in which I want to generate an `Interface` from the data I have in an `object`, I don't know if this is possible but I can't do it.

What I do is the following:

1. I get the `JSON` Database Object with the results of a query
2. From the values of that object I need to create a dynamic interface to add an ArrayList to each of those values, and thus avoid modifying the interface every time the database values change

This is the `object` I get from database:

```
interface Auto {
  autoType: string
}
let autoActive: Auto[] = [
  {  "autoType": "Car"},
  {  "autoType": "Motorcycle"},
  {  "autoType": "Truck"},
  {  "autoType": "Plane"}
]

console.log(autoActive.map(Object.values).toString()); // Car,Motorcycle,Truck,Plane
```

This is the `interface` I need to create from the above data (`AutoBrand`) from the `genericObject` model:

```
interface genericObject {
  [key: string]: any;
}
interface AutoBrand extends genericObject {
  "Car": Array<string>,
  "Motorcycle": Array<string>,
  "Truck": Array<string>,
  "Plane": Array<string>
}
```

What I want to obtain from this is to generate a constant `object` to assign the titles to each final file, this is an example of the final class that I want to obtain, and then extract the titles from here:

```
export class HeaderConst {
  static readonly headerConst: AutoBrand = {
    "Car": [
      "Model",
      "Total",
      "Age"
    ],
    "Motorcycle": [
      "Model",
      "Total",
      "Age"
    ],
    "Truck": [
      "Model",
      "Total",
      "Age"
    ],
    "Plane": [
      "Model",
      "Total",
      "Age"
    ]
  }
  public static getConstants(elem: string) {
    return elem.split(".").reduce((elm: any, i: any) => {
        return elm[i];
    }, this.headerConst);
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need to create a compile-time type from runtime information? (You can't, but whatever it is you're trying to do probably does have a solution, just a different one.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just updated the question with the reason of what I'm trying to do, I don't know if you understand

Comment: What information exactly do you have at compile time?  You’ve already queried some database and gotten… JSON?  And then that JSON got dropped into a TS file with `let autoActive: Auto[] =` before it?  When the DB contents change, how does your TS source code get updated? You certainly can generate interfaces from sufficiently strongly typed values, but you need these values directly in your TS code somewhere. So you should let us know how this happens (because we don’t have access to your environment).

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Your JSON only exists at runtime, and TypeScript interfaces do not exist at runtime at all.